# function not worked synchronously in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passwords

I am little bit confused with my code it's not worked synchronusly as it's should be.  I use everyauth to do authentication.

```
registerUser(function(newUserAttrs) {
        var login = newUserAttrs[this.loginKey()];
        user.CreateNewUser(newUserAttrs.login, newUserAttrs.password, newUserAttrs.email, function(res, err) {
            if(!err) {
                return usersByLogin[login] = newUserAttrs;
            }
            else {
                throw err;
            }

        });

    })
```

in another file  I have write this code

```
exports.CreateNewUser = function(login, pass, mail, callback) {

    var sql = "insert into `user`(login,mail,pass) values(?,?,?)";
    client.query(sql, [login, mail, pass], function(err, results, fields) {
        if(!err) {
            callback(results);
            console.log('test')
        }
        else {
            callback(results, err);
        }
    });
};
```

This code are working fine. I have tested him. the only problem is they are working synchronosly (as normal). Can someone explain me what thing I have done in wrong way that make it async. I want to get it done in sync way.

The current code give me error (it's make a entry in database and produce error on browser)

```
Error: Step registerUser of `password` is promising: userOrErrors ; however, the step returns nothing. Fix the step by returning the expected values OR by returning a Promise that promises said values.
    at Object.exec (E:\proj\Node\node_modules\everyauth\lib\step.js:68:11)
    at E:\proj\Node\node_modules\everyauth\lib\stepSequence.js:26:38
    at [object Object].callback (E:\proj\Node\node_modules\everyauth\lib\promise.js:13:12)
    at RouteTriggeredSequence._bind (E:\proj\Node\node_modules\everyauth\lib\stepSequence.js:25:20)
    at RouteTriggeredSequence.start (E:\proj\Node\node_modules\everyauth\lib\stepSequence.js:52:33)
    at RouteTriggeredSequence.routeHandler (E:\proj\Node\node_modules\everyauth\lib\routeTriggeredSequence.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (native)
    at nextMiddleware (E:\proj\Node\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\router.js:175:25)
    at param (E:\proj\Node\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\router.js:183:16)
    at pass (E:\proj\Node\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\router.js:191:10)
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem here, but the convention in Node is to execute `callback(error, results)` and not `callback(results, error)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two pieces of code you present are asynchronous and not synchronous! 
With everyauth, to be able to handle asynchronous user creation you should use a Promise. So your code will be something like :

```
registerUser(function(newUserAttrs) {
    var promise = this.Promise();
    var login = newUserAttrs[this.loginKey()];
    user.CreateNewUser(newUserAttrs.login, newUserAttrs.password, newUserAttrs.email, function(res, err) {
        if(!err) {
            return promise.fulfill(newUserAttrs);
        }
        else {
            promise.fulfill(user);
        }

    });

})
```

Without promise you couldn't be sure that your new user has been added in your database. But if it doesn't matter you could have something like that:

```
registerUser(function(newUserAttrs) {
    var login = newUserAttrs[this.loginKey()];
    user.CreateNewUser(newUserAttrs.login, newUserAttrs.password, newUserAttrs.email, function(res, err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
    return newUserAttrs;

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing a database query, this code has to be asynchronous. The anonymous function you pass to `client.query` will not be called until the database query is complete, so your `callback` gets called asynchronously.

You will need to treat this all as asynchronous, so for instance you'll have to trigger some other callback instead of returning the user object/throwing.